# Sublime 3: can I change the font/size of comments?

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a way to make the comments a different (smaller) font from the rest of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Sublime supports the idea that each `view` (editing pane) can have a unique list of settings, which includes `font_face` and `font_size`, it doesn't support multiple font faces or sizes from within a single `view`.

As such, it's not possible to have some elements use a different font face or size, although it's possible to change the font style to `bold` or `italic`, which is controlled by your color scheme.